# Cannot add accounts to messages on Mac

Tags: macos, mojave, messages, accounts

on my MacBook Pro Mid 2015 Version 10.14.6 I cannot add any other account (Jabber, G-Chat/Hangouts etc,) to messages.

Can you still add third party accounts to messages?

I tried to add it over online accounts (no option to tick messages) and I tried to add it in "message".

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What steps are you taking to add accounts?  What error message(s) did you receive?  You can [edit] your question to include this info.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Apple’s [support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202549) about the messages app, nowhere does it mention being able to use third-party messaging services. Whereas in 2014, according to [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20141216105040/https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202549), the article said 3rd party messaging platforms where supported. It appears Apple has removed this feature.

Comment: interesting that apple removes a feature and no-one seems to care :(

Comment: There may not have been many people using it. If that’s the case, it would have been very easy to get rid of it without many people realizing anything changed. Although it would still be a nice feature to have.